# If you finish a world without fighting the Broodal, can you still fight them later?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

I've just seen that in a speedrun: If you collect enough moons to move on to the next world, and cash them in at the ship, the broodal ship just leaves.

Does that mean that the Broodal fight wont happen, so you missed the triple moon it gives? Or if you go to the arena, even without the ship you will have the fight happen?

Clip where this happens : https://go.twitch.tv/videos/200296642?t=11m45s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, you can come back to a world later and fight the Broodals.**

If you leave the Sand Kingdom before beating the boss, the Broodal ship won’t be visible when you return to the level.

However, if you go to the top of the Inverted Pyramid, the ship will return and the fight will play out normally

Comment: What makes you say the ship won't be visible? At least in the Luncheon Kingdom, that's not the case. I beat the game after skipping basically all the Broodal fights, came back to Luncheon, and the mission intro and everything was still set up for the Broodal fight. Their ship was visible.

Comment: @ArrowCase I accidentally left the  Sand Kingdom early before fighting the Broodals on my 1st playthrough. I don’t remember the ship being present when I came back, but I could be misremembering.

Comment: Yesterday, I left the Sand Kingdom early and doing so made Bowser's ship fly away from the Inverted Pyramid. When I went to the boss arena at the top, the Broodals airship flew in.

Comment: The ship only flies away in Sand Kingdom. In all other Kingdoms, the ship continues to circle the platform on which the battle takes place.