# Consequence of charging the Odyssey before visiting boss level?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

I got enough Power Moons to charge the Odyssey before getting to the Showdown on the Inverted Pyramid (Sand Kingdom). When I charged the Odyssey, Bowser flew away and I was asked to choose a fork in the road.

It looks like I can still go beat the boss and get the multi-moon on the Inverted Pyramid, but Bowser’s airship is no longer there. Did I miss anything? (Power ups, power moons, etc.?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[If you go back to the top of the inverted pyramid, the Broodals' ship will appear and challenge you to a battle as normal.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/321458/if-you-finish-a-world-without-fighting-the-broodal-can-you-still-fight-them-lat)

Everything else in the level should be exactly the same as it was before Bowser's ship left.

> The one exception is if you have completed the story, the underground section will contain the oversized wedding ring. This doesn't make a difference to any gameplay, however.